# Como alinear texto e imagen en Html

Tags: html, imagen, div

Estoy presentando el siguiente problema al intentar alinear una imagen al lado de un texto centrado, estoy creando un `div` para la imagen y otro para el texto, pero aun así no funciona.

El siguiente es el código que estoy utilizando para alinear la imagen con el texto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Templete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table th {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

    <div>
        <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="150" height="45">
    </div>

<div id="page_1">

    <div style="border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 170px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 553px;overflow: hidden;">       
        <div style="float: left; border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
            <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080;">Funcionamiento</p>
            <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: left; padding-left: 65px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080; line-height: 32px;">Desconocido</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguien sabe de otra sugerencia que me pueda orientar en como alinear correctamente la imagen con el texto, como se aprecia en el código se visualiza que la imagen esta mas arriba que el texto centrado.

Answer (score 4):

Un pequeño ejemplo de como centrar elementos dentro de un Div, con la propiedad Flex de Css, Te recomiendo que veas más a detalle esta propiedad para que puedas posicionar los elementos HTML a tu gusto.
Documentación extra: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
  .container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:100%;
    gap:5px;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="150" height="45">
</div>
<div class="container">
     <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="150" height="45">
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los div son elementos de bloque, significa que siempre se colocarán uno debajo del otro, para alinear los dos div, hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero yo recomiendo colocar en los estilos del body la propiedad display:flex;

Display flex los coloca uno al lado del otro, pero a su vez, le da al elemento padre (en este caso sería body) varias propiedades css para alinear a sus elementos hijos, por ejemplo, justify-content: center; alinearía sus elementos hijos al centro en el eje horizontal.

A muchos les cuesta entender flex, pero es bastante útil cuando lo dominas, te dejo la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Podrías aportarme un ejemplo usando `display:flex;` en base a tu respuesta usando como referencia el código de mi pregunta, para así poderle dar una validez y que a los demás usuarios visitantes del sitio les pueda servir como ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice Jonathan García en la respuesta anterior (¡si te sirve esta respuesta, el mérito es suyo!) utilizando `display:flex;` en el contenedor, puedes "jugar" con el contenido de varia formas, en este caso utilizando la propiedad `justify-content: center;`.
En el código a continuación, he añadido un DIV #contenedor para no utilizar el BODY, pero podrías eliminarlo y aplicarle las propiedades CSS al BODY directamente.

También he coloreado los DIV con el único objetivo de que se vea en el resultado como funciona cada DIV, naturalmente has de quitar estas propiedades para tu página, comprueba el resultado con la opción "Página completa" para verlo correctamente, por lo demás el código es exacto al tuyo.

Creo haber entendido tu pregunta, si no es así, coméntalo y estaré encantado de ayudarte.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Templete</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
         table th {
         text-align: center !important;
         }
         #page_1
         {
         background-color: silver;
         }
         #imagen_1
         {
         background-color: red;
         }
         #contenedor
         {
         background-color: black;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <div id ="contenedor">
         <div id="imagen_1">
            <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="150" height="45">
         </div>
         <div id="page_1">
            <div style="border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 170px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 553px;overflow: hidden;">
               <div style="float: left; border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
                  <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080;">Funcionamiento</p>
                  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: left; padding-left: 65px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080; line-height: 32px;">Desconocido</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

aquí te muestro un ejemplo usando Flex

Básicamente "encerré" la imagen y el texto en div's por separado y luego "encerré " esos dos div's en un div superior (**.col-wrap**)

**.col-wrap** le damos **display: flex;** y **align-items: center;** para alinear los dos div's verticalmente

Ahora a **.col-img** le coloque **width: auto;** para que el div tome el ancho de la imagen que contiene y a **.col-txt** le coloque **width: 100%** para que tome en teoría lo que resta del ancho permitido

A ese **.col-txt** le coloque **display: flex;** y luego **flex-direction: column;** para que ordene los párrafos que contiene de forma vertical, ya que Flex por default ordena los elementos de forma horizontal. Luego le asigne **align-items: center;** y **justify-content:center;** para que esos párrafos estén en el centro tanto vertical como horizontalmente en **.col-txt**

Espero te ayude.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Templete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .col-wrap {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center:
    }
    .col-img {
        width: auto;
    }
    .col-txt {
        width: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .col-txt p {
        font: bold 27px 'Helvetica';
        line-height: 27px;
        color: #000080;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0!important;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="col-wrap">
        <div class="col-img">
            <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="250">
        </div>
        <div id="page_1" class="col-txt">
            <p>Funcionamiento</p>
            <p>Desconocido</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno esta es mi humilde opinión:

un ejemplo con clase, sin clases jejeje

```css
body>div>div:first-of-type {
    background: URL("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px auto;
  background-position: right center;
}
body>div>div>div>p{
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 27px 'Helvetica';
  color: #000080;
}
body>div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>       
      <div>
        <p>Funcionamiento<br>
           Desconocido</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

la propiedad grid ayuda mucho y mas cuando estas trabajando con responsivo
te aconsejo unos cuantos tutoriales
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBOUSrMqlSQ

Answer (score 1):

Mi primer consejo sería no utilizar estilos en línea, agregalos solo a tu bloque de css.
Eliminé todos los estilos en línea e hice algunas modificaciones.
Adjunto código con comentarios para que te sirva de ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Templete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
        /* Primero quitamos margin y padding de todos los elementos del documento. */
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        /* Creamos contenedor flex alineando y justificando todos los elementos al centro, */
        header{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        /* Div image_div y titles serán contenedores flex con dirección de columna. */
        #image_div,
        #titles{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        /* Aplicamos ancho y alto de imagen. */
        .image{
            width: 150px;
            height: 45px;
        }
        /* Agregamos un padding-left para separar el texto de la imagen. */
        #titles{
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        /* Damos formato a los textos. */
        .title{
            font: bold 27px 'Helvetica';
            color: #000080;
        }
        /* Agregamos un padding-left para el segundo texto. */
        .title_2{
            padding-left: 65px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Creamos una etiqueta header que contendra los divs image_div  y titles
            los cuales contendrán las etiquetas sin agregar estilos en línea. -->
    <header>
        <div id='image_div'>
            <img class='image' src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="titles">
                <p class='title'>Funcionamiento</p>
                <p class='title title_2'>Desconocido</p>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El uso de flex te ayuda a resolver tu tema, investiga como manejar jerarquías de contenedores para tener estructuras ordenadas, saludos

```
<div id="page_1">
    <div style="border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 170px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 553px;overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
        <div>
            <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/69/539/png-transparent-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-programmer-logo-others.png" width="150" height="45">
        </div>
 
        <div style="float: left; border: none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
            <p style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080;">Funcionamiento</p>
            <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: left; padding-left: 65px; font: bold 27px 'Helvetica'; color: #000080; line-height: 32px;">Desconocido</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```